# How do you update a button's visual state in a Google Add-On without inserting a new card?

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I am creating a CRM helper for Gmail using Google Workspace Add-Ons. I have nearly all of the functionality built out, except for the SMS provider. Right now, I have a form section with a form input and button, displayed below.

```js
function createSendSMSSection(phone, client) {
  let section = CardService.newCardSection();

  let input = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName("sms_input")
    .setTitle("Type in a SMS message here!")
    .setMultiline(true);
  input.setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("handleInputChange"));

  let button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("SEND")
    .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
    .setDisabled(true);
  let action = CardService.newAction()
    .setMethodName("sendSMS")
    .setParameters({ "phone": phone, "clientjson": JSON.stringify(client) });
  button.setOnClickAction(action);


  let kv = CardService.newKeyValue()
    .setContent(' ')
    .setButton(button);

  section.addWidget(input);
  section.addWidget(kv);
  return section;
}
```

By default, the send button is disabled. My intention for this section is that the user will enter in text into the `input`, which will call `handleInputChange()`. This function will check if the form input has any content, and if it does, enable the send button. However, when I tried doing this:

```js
function handleInputChange(event) {
  const inputarr = event.formInputs["sms_input"];
  let input = ''
  if (inputarr)
  {
    for (inputrow of inputarr) {
      input = " " + inputrow;
    }
  }

  input = input.trim();

  if (input && input != '') {
    State.SENDDISABLED = false;
    State.SMS_Body = input;
  }
  else {
    State.SENDDISABLED = true;
    State.SMS_Body = null;
  }
}
```

The button's state doesn't change at all! I know that I can create a new card with an enabled button, and call `updateCard()` to replace the old card with a new card. However, this creates a very laggy experience, since a new card would have to be created on the first keystroke. Is there any way I can just update this button's state without rendering a new card?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the `handleInputChange` function gets called correctly, but it fails to activate the button. There is one simple change that you can make to correctly refresh the button: using the [`updateCard()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/navigation?hl=en#updatecardcard) method just after updating the disabled boolean. One approach of developing a solution with this method is including the line:

```js
CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(yourCardObject);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't answer my question. I wanted to know if there was a way to call ```updateCard()``` without creating (thus rerendering) the whole card object, since I call a REST API during the card generation that takes time to process. After reading through the Google docs, I know now there is no way to rerender at a ```CardSection``` level.

Comment: If using [`updateCard()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/navigation?hl=en#updatecardcard) is not a valid approach in your scenario, you may use different alternatives. Please visit the [navigation best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/navigation#navigation_best_practice) guide to learn more.